# How can I position elements outside their container with ~20px showing?

Tags: css, position, alignment

([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EFXtg/3/))

I have a `<ul>` with its `<li>`s aligned to the right. I'd like them to be positioned such that only about 20px of the element is showing on the right side of the `<ul>`, and on hover they go to their normal positions. This will be combined with `overflow: hidden;` on the container so the elements are partially hidden to begin with and slide in from the side (with CSS3 transitions).

In this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EFXtg/3/) (`overflow: visible` for illustration) I was able to slide the elements in to the right position, but how do I align them such that they lie with 20px inside their container to start with? The best I could do was keep them right-aligned and push them all the way outside their container.

I played with changing the elements' widths, but if they contain multiple words the text wraps and the height changes (or with `overflow: hidden` the words just disappear when the width is too small), which is unacceptable.

It's acceptable (but less interesting and less preferable) to use fixed-width `<li>`s, if necessary, but I'd like to see other solutions.

Comment: So you want them hidden with only 20px showing on the right side of the `ul`, then slide in fully?

Comment: @Qtax: Yep, that's it. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the UL itself has a fixed width, you could position the LI's ({UL_width} - 20) pixels from the left of the UL. I would probably do something like...

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item #1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item #2</span></li>
</ul>
...
```

The following CSS should give you the desired effect...

```
ul { width: 200px; }
ul li {
    position: relative;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 180px;
}
```

Something along those lines should do the trick. Then just do a rollover to adjust your left property of the ul li span.

**NEW CSS**

```
ul { width: 200px; }
ul li {
    width: 200px;
    text-indent: 180px;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I can live with a fixed-width `ul`, but is there a way to do this without extra markup (the `span`s)?

Comment: @jtbandes you could also do this with text indent and adjust this property accordingly on your rollover. See my edit in the code above.